# Is it possible to add multiple documents in meteor through collection.insert()?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

I like to add multiple documents at once in a collection in meteor.

[MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) supports this from 2.2:

```
db.collection.insert([{docNumber: 1},{docNumber: 2}])
```

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour also in Meteor? Something like:

```
myCollection.insert([{docNumber: 1},{docNumber: 2}])
```

Currently this will be added as one document. I can unfortunately not live with an iterator because the use case is loading more than 100'000 documents. This is to slow with single inserts.

Answer (score 8):

Batch insertion isn't yet possible with Meteor. Though you could make an iterator to help you insert documents in an array

```
var docs = [{docNumber: 1},{docNumber: 2}];

_.each(docs, function(doc) {
    myCollection.insert(doc);
});
```

It might be possible to do it on the server end, albeit with a bit of modifications to expose a bulk insertion method. The problem with this though is this code wouldn't work on the client end.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I have but a usecase where I neet to load > 100'000 documents. This is just to slow this way.

Comment: You might find it better to look through the https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/mongo-livedata package and try to add in a bulk insert function that exposes the new 2.2 bulk insert method. The problem with this though is you have to keep doing it to keep meteor up to date every version until they make an official bulk insert method. If you're willing to put through it could help your use case with >100k documents.

Comment: Akshat is correct, and if you need inspiration you can use this PR: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1254

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a simple script to bulk insert. It works only on the client side by inserting documents to the collection without reactivity. only the last item will call the reactive computations.

```
insertBulk = function(collection, documents){
  if(collection) {
    return _.compact(_.map(documents, function(item){
        if(_.isObject(item)) {

            var _id = collection._makeNewID();

            // insert with reactivity only on the last item
            if(_.last(documents) === item)
                _id = collection.insert(item);

            // insert without reactivity
            else {
                item._id = _id;
                collection._collection._docs._map[_id] = item;
            }

            return _id;
        }
    }));
  }
}
```

You can find an example script including removebulk() function here: https://gist.github.com/frozeman/88a3e47679dd74242cab

Comment: This is a nice solution for the client, should really speed up things! I'm looking for the same on the server right now.